# Editable div ignoring `\n`

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with `attr("contentEditable",true)`. The problem if I enter text

> 111111111111
>
> 2222222222222222
>
> 33333333333333333

It simply take `1111111111111111112222222222222222222233333333333`

I am taking div text using `$.text()`

Comment: @adeneo see my comment

Comment: @Royi check ur example its not working

Comment: @RoyiNamir - the question says nothing about using jQuery's text() to render HTML, it's clearly about why newlines are not rendered in a DIV, which is of course because HTML doesn't care about whitespace and newlines, and that makes it a perfect duplicate.

Comment: @adeneo see this one :  http://jsbin.com/najuyajo/4/edit try this one , in the new div the lines are preserved.

Comment: It should also be noted that the answer in the duplicate question, i.e. setting the white-space to pre or pre-wrap solves this issue.

Comment: @adeneo my example prove that no need for css ( here) to solve the line breaks ( i repeat : in this particular case)

Comment: @RoyiNamir - That's because you're typing into a content editable element, so each line is wrapped in a DIV element. That's not at all related to inserting strings with newlines into a content editable DIV.

Comment: @Royi ur example still not working

Comment: @adeneo You see ?  I didn't know that it injects divs ....:-) thanks for elaborate !

Comment: `pre` or `pre-wrap` didnt work

Answer (score 6):

Because `\n` is not a newline character to web browsers. [Web browsers ignore whitespace](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/f/blfaqwhitespace.htm). If you want to display a new line you must add a `<br>` wherever you see a new line character.

Comment: I am trying `dt.text().replace(/\n/g, '<br />')` but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

use `<br>` for new line **\n** is for source code